# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nik7.jpg'

Tags: python-imaging-library

**Error**

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nik7.jpg'
```

I am trying to read an image but get the above error.

**Code:**

```
from PIL import Image
pil_im=Image.open('C"\Users\nikhil\Desktop\nik7.jpg' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You're missing a colon
- `\` escapes the next character, so either use two (double escape): `\\`, or use the Unix-style `/` which works on Windows too:

  `pil_im = Image.open('C:/Users/nikhi/Desktop/nik7.jpg')`